Realm DB issue after converting Groovy DSL Gradle to Kotlin DSL and TOML
I converted my gradle file into kts based and created toml but realm db case i am getting error help me in this
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.realm:realm-kotlin:1.12.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.realm:realm-kotlin:1.12.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://packages.mongodb.com/maven/io/realm/realm-kotlin/1.12.0/realm-kotlin-1.12.0.pom
            > Resetting to invalid mark

* Try:

my gradle conversion is as
"

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
to all sub-projects/modules. plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt) apply false


// Apply Hilt plugin directly
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48.1" apply false
id("io.realm.kotlin") version "3.0.0" apply false }


"
and app level

plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt)
id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin") // Add the Hilt plugin here
id("io.realm.kotlin") version "3.0.0"
}
android {
namespace = "com.scannerdoc.myapplication"
compileSdk = 34
defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.scannerdoc.myapplication"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "11"
}

}
dependencies {
implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
implementation(libs.material)
implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
testImplementation(libs.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
// Dagger Hilt
implementation(libs.hilt.android)
kapt(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx) // Lifecycle ViewModel
implementation(libs.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)  // Lifecycle LiveData

//    implementation(libs.library.sync)
implementation(libs.realm.kotlin) }


are you trying to migrate to only Kotlin DSL or Kotlin DSL + TOML?

I am doing this one Kotlin DSL + TOML

Then you can define your plugins in TOML file itself and then you can use it in project gradle and apply to module gradle like you do for dependencies
